# Angular 7 and Cake PHP integration

Tags: angular, cakephp

I having been using Angular for a long time now. But I want to know if it is possible to use Angular as font-end and CakePHP as backend? if possible. how do i integrate Angular with Cake PHP

Answer (score 0):

Angular 7 frontend, rest API backend (you can create rest API with PHP or with some another technologies)

- separate implementations, optional
- separate repositories, optional
- separate deployments, optional